# Correlation between min and max of two uniform variables

Tags: random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d uniform random variables drawn from $(0,1)$. Let $A$ be $\min(X,Y)$ and $B$ be $\max(X,Y)$, what’s the correlation between $A$ and $B $ ?

Comment: @Arthur  
I used a dirty way. I used some programming language like Matlab to generate independent uniform variables and then computed the max, min between them. The results indicated that the correlation is 0.5.
However computing it formally is still questionable.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline A=\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^y x\,dx+\int_y^1y\,dx\right]dy=\int_0^1\left[\frac{y^2}2+y(1-y)\right]dy\\
=\frac13.$$

$$\overline B=\int_0^1\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^y y\,dx+\int_y^1x\,dx\right]dy=\int_0^1\left[y^2+\frac{1-y^2}2\right]dy\\
=\frac23.$$

$$\overline{AB}=\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(x,y)\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^y xy\,dx+\int_y^1yx\,dx\right]dy\\
=\int_0^1\int_0^1xy\,dx\,dy=\frac14.$$

Remains to compute the standard deviations.

Comment: That last integral evaluates to 0.25, not 1

Comment: @Mathemagical: yep, I was inattentive.